# 「URLから動画の取得が終了したら」という条件つきで実行したい処理

Tags: swift

「URLから動画の取得が終了したら」という条件つきで実行したい処理があります。
(動画の取得中には実行したくない)

このような処理を実装する場合に、どのような方法が考えられますか。
以下のように非同期処理で実現しようとしたところ、クラッシュしました。

```
DispatchQueue.global().sync {

   let url = URL(string: "http://movie.mov")
   let player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
   let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
   playerViewController.player = player
   let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: videoPlayer)
   self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
   player.play()

   DispatchQueue.main.sync {
　　　//ここで処理を実行したい
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

動画の取得を別スレッドで、UIの更新系の処理をmainスレッドで処理です。
syncやasyncの中に書かれた処理は普通に上から下に向けて処理されます。
下のようにすることで動画を取得してからデータ/UIの更新となります。

```
// ここは一般的には非同期 async で実行します
// 同期的でよい場合はDispatchQueueを使う必要はありません。
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    //ここでURLから動画の取得

    // ここはasyncでもsyncでもOK。　下に違いを記述。
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        // ここでデータの更新とUIの更新
    }

    // DispatchQueue.main.syncの場合、ここに処理があれば、DispatchQueue.main.syncの実行後に処理される

    // DispatchQueue.main.asyncにした場合、ここに処理があれば非同期に実行される
}
```